# How to display JSON form fields in ExtJS Tabpanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am getting form fields from the database. I need to create tabs dynamically and need to display fields inside those tabs based on the index.

> Example:

The variable matrix length is 4. It should create 4 tabs.
matrix[0] contents should go to first tab. matrix[1] contents should go to second tab. matrix[2] contents should go to third tab and matrix[3] contents should go to fourth tab.

```
var matrix = [
    [{
        "allowBlank": false,
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Full Name <span class=\"red\">*</span>",
        "labelWidth": 180,
        "width": 500,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "name": "refDataName",
        "fieldsetId": 1,
        "colspan": 1,
        "maxLength": 100
    }, {
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "First Name",
        "labelWidth": 180,
        "width": 500,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "name": "refDataOne",
        "fieldsetId": 1,
        "colspan": 1,
        "maxLength": 100
    }, {
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Last Name",
        "labelWidth": 180,
        "width": 500,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "name": "refDataTwo",
        "fieldsetId": 1,
        "colspan": 1,
        "maxLength": 100
    }],
    [{
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Parent Name",
        "labelWidth": 180,
        "width": 500,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "name": "refDataThree",
        "fieldsetId": 2,
        "colspan": 1,
        "maxLength": 100
    }],
    [{
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Address",
        "labelWidth": 180,
        "width": 500,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "name": "refDataFive",
        "fieldsetId": 3,
        "colspan": 1,
        "maxLength": 100
    }],
    []
];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a code writing service :) You should post the code that you have tried, if you can't figure it out on your own I suggest you do some more research and give it a go. If that still doesn't work out you can come back here **with** your code and ask for some pointers.

Comment: I have tried something,

for (var z = 0; z < matrix.length; z++) {
          if(matrix[z].length > 0) {
            object = {};
            object['xtype'] = "tabpanel";
            object['title'] = "Form - " +z;
            object['layout'] = {type: "table", columns: 2};
            object['defaults'] = {anchor: "100%", bodyStyle: "padding:40px", labelStyle: "padding-left: 45px"};
            object['collapsible'] = true;
            object['items'] = matrix[z];
          }
      }
      this.getView().add(object);

Could not get.

Comment: Can you try formatting your code as such?

Comment: Sorry, you can check it here: https://paste.ofcode.org/W8zdMBn4S73cQJJT5AWjcz

Comment: External links hurt the longevity of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is making multiple tabpanels inside the view. Remove the following code:

```
object['xtype'] = "tabpanel";
```

And add the `object` to the `tabpanel`.

```js
Ext.application({
      name: 'Fiddle',

      launch: function() {
      var matrix = [
      [
          {
            "allowBlank": false,
            "xtype": "textfield",
            "fieldLabel": "Full Name <span class=\"red\">*</span>",
            "labelWidth": 180,
            "width": 500,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "name": "refDataName",
            "fieldsetId": 1,
            "colspan": 1,
            "maxLength": 100
        },
        {
            "xtype": "textfield",
            "fieldLabel": "First Name",
            "labelWidth": 180,
            "width": 500,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "name": "refDataOne",
            "fieldsetId": 1,
            "colspan": 1,
            "maxLength": 100
        },
        {
            "xtype": "textfield",
            "fieldLabel": "Last Name",
            "labelWidth": 180,
            "width": 500,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "name": "refDataTwo",
            "fieldsetId": 1,
            "colspan": 1,
            "maxLength": 100
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "xtype": "textfield",
            "fieldLabel": "Parent Name",
            "labelWidth": 180,
            "width": 500,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "name": "refDataThree",
            "fieldsetId": 2,
            "colspan": 1,
            "maxLength": 100
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "xtype": "textfield",
            "fieldLabel": "Address",
            "labelWidth": 180,
            "width": 500,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "name": "refDataFive",
            "fieldsetId": 3,
            "colspan": 1,
            "maxLength": 100
        }
    ],
    []
]; 
var tabpanel=Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
});
for (var z = 0; z < matrix.length; z++) {
          if(matrix[z].length > 0) {
            object = {};
            object['title'] = "Form - " +z;
            object['layout'] = {type: "table", columns: 2};
            object['defaults'] = {anchor: "100%", bodyStyle: "padding:40px", labelStyle: "padding-left: 45px"};
            object['collapsible'] = true;
            object['items'] = matrix[z];
            tabpanel.add(object);
          }
      }
        }
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```